# CSS- How to move a box on this page to the center

Tags: css

I'm trying to align a box on this page but having trouble trying to do it. I've put it together in a stye sheet. I would like the three boxes at the bottom of the page to be centered with the image in the style sheet. Any help would be greatly appreciated, and thank you in advance.

Here is the page: http://www.sevenbarfoundation.org/emails/landing/

Answer (score 2):

First question. Why the structure of that site is based on tables? You should make that site with `div` elements, not `table`. Leave `table` for tabular data, not site structure.

To answer your question, just add CSS property `margin: 0 auto;` to `div` that the form is placed in:

```
<div style="width:317px; height:254px; margin: 0 auto;">
```

Comment: It looks like it might be a HTML email, so he's probably stuck with tables. Sigh... poor guy

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Ventus.
You should also read about fixed positioning and negative margins(good for old browsers)